# Parse/FacebookUtils and FacebookCore not working due to dependency conflict.

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I use 'Parse/FacebookUtils' in order to log in with Parse, 
and I use the rest of the FacebookCore for Analytics and other stuff.

The problem is that 'Parse/FacebookUtils' has FacebookCore as a dependency, with an old version. This old version doesn't compile with Swift 4.2.

Thanks in advance

```
pod 'FacebookCore', '~> 0.5.0'
pod 'Parse/FacebookUtils'


[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "FBSDKCoreKit":
  In Podfile:
    FacebookCore (~> 0.5.0) was resolved to 0.5.0, which depends on
      FBSDKCoreKit (~> 4.37)

    Parse/FacebookUtils was resolved to 1.17.1, which depends on
      FBSDKCoreKit (~> 4.28.0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, manage to figure this one of.

You can specify your own spec file, and modify it:

```
pod 'Parse/FacebookUtils', :podspec => '/path/to/Parse.podspec.json'
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying that Parse/FacebookUtils only supports up to FBSDKCoreKit v4.28.0 but the pod FacebookCore v0.5.0 requires FBSDKCoreKit v4.37 (a newer version). If you change your pod file to

```
pod 'FacebookCore'
pod 'Parse/FacebookUtils'
```

It should pick a version of FacebookCore which uses an older version of FBSDKCoreKit.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, however, there are a bug in the old version of the FBSDKCoreKit which prevent it to run on the latest iOS.

Comment: Another option is to fork https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX and update the ParseFacebookUtils so it runs on the latest FBSDKCoreKit - not ideal but may be a last resort.